# why i have http 405 error in requests and how can i use api?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

hi i am noob programer and i need send data in site with api. But things did not go well and I got into trouble.

my code is:

```
data = {
    "‫‪industryId‬‬": 3,
    "‫‪chimneyId‬‬": 10,
    "‫‪parameterId‬‬": 3203,
    "‫‪quantity‬‬": 12
}

json_dump_data = json.dumps(data)

URL = "https://iranemp.ir/api/industryParameterMonitoring/Create/Quantity"

HEDER = {
    'Host': 'iranemp.ir',
    "X-Api-Key": X_API_KEY,
    "X-Token-Key": X_TOKEN_KEY,
    
}


response = requests.post(url=URL, headers=HEDER, json=json_dump_data)
```

i tested this send in postman and i got answer!
and my keys be shuld use in header!

on postman, host key in 'HEADER' equal to iranemp.ir.

If I do not use the host key, a 405 error will occur, but if I use it and give it any value other than the host, I will get a 404 error!

what is my wrong?

Comment: 405 means "method not allowed". Which could mean a lot. Perhaps you're not allowed to post to the given url. The solution to your problem will be in the specification of the API.

Comment: "but if I use it and give it any value other than the host, I will get a 404 error!". So now your error has changed from your title; great. Anyway: a 404 is simple: the url/resource does not exist. You probably have a typo in your url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you sent `POST` to endpoint not supporting this verb.
To became aware which [verb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)s are allowed you might send [`OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) and check what is under `Allow` in headers. Example of using `requests` for retrieving `OPTIONS`:

```
import requests
r = requests.options("http://www.example.com")
allow = r.headers.get("Allow", "allow not found")
print(allow)
```

output

```
OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
```

If your endpoint does support `POST` then check if it does data as JSON in API documentation.

Comment: Hi I Am EmadDeve and my problem is solved!

Thank You @Daweo You Right!
my site address is wrong!